# Looking for hands on example or reference for SOAP API integration

Tags: apex, soap-api, webservices, integration, wsdl2apex

I am looking for some help in understanding Salesforce SOAP integration. Also, what would you suggestion,if I am a non-java person then the efforts i need to take up via books and tool to learn the concept?(already know Apex and web service concept using another CRM,but how to use /configure is not yet clear in salesforce).Checked SOAP Dev ref guide, and without executing any samples,not finding it much helpful.

Any worksheets that can be used to understand the below concepts : ---

1. Generation and consumption of WSDL in SF.
2. How to write the code to call these proxy services created by wsdl import.
3. On getting a response ; how to capture the response...
4. Can SOAPUI tool be used in salesforce for testing?
5. How to implement secure exchange of SOAP messages between systems.
6. How do we test inbound and outbound webservice SOAP request from salesforce?

Comment: Note that consuming WSDL in Salesforce (where Apex code is generated to typically allow Apex to call out to a web service and process the response) can be frustrating because the tooling ("Generate Apex from WSDL" AKA wsdl2apex) is limited in the XML schema elements it supports. If you run into problems, Google to understand the limitations and work-arounds better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not too tough, getting the environemnt setup is the biggest hurdle, after that java is pretty darn close to Apex!  Maybe checkout a blog post I made a long time ago, on getting the environment setup.  Once you have that done, generate either an enterprise or partner WSDL and off you go.  Also, my blog has the info on how to get the WSDL into your Java project.  Otherwise, the SFDC SOAP developers guide is a great reference too!

[Setting up the environemnt](http://anotherforceblog.blogspot.com/2013/03/setting-up-jdk-se616-and-eclipse-for.html)

[Generating the WSDL](http://anotherforceblog.blogspot.com/2013/03/generating-wsdl-from-salesforce-and.html)

[SFDC SOAP Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/)